# Super and arrow key has started switching tty

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, tty

I normally use <kbd>Super</kbd> and Arrow Key to snap a window to one-half of the screen or the other.

About 5 minutes ago, it started to switch between `tty` consoles. I gather that this is intended to happen when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> Key is used, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> key does have that behaviour.

How can I stop my <kbd>Super</kbd> key from acting like the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key in this case?

Comment: Both Alt+Arrow and Super+Arrow do normally switch to the previous/next TTY, but only for the terminal TTYs 1-6 and unused video TTYs (normally 8-12). If you have a desktop environment running in a TTY, it normally intercepts the shortcut and performs a custom action (or nothing) instead of switching TTYs. No idea what exactly went wrong in your case though, maybe check the system's shortcut settings, those in CompizConfig etc.

Comment: @ByteCommander for some reason, GDM runs in tty2... not sure why it dies, but it has for a while and I don't know what changed 5 minutes ago...

Comment: I did have the same problem in Ubuntu after it upgraded some packages, but a restart fixed the problem.

Comment: @landas Yeah, I think I might have just finished running an upgrade. A restart fixed it too.

Comment: I've since had to reinstall my computer. So I can no-longer reproduce this (and it was fixed by a restart anyway). Closing it because of those two reasons.

Comment: This seems to still be getting views. If you’ve got this problem, please - read [ask], and then ask a new question!

Comment: It seems this is a reported bug, you can track it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1508146

Comment: @JW. That’s Alt not Super, I wonder if the increased views on this question are due to people confusing Alt with Super

Comment: It started happening to me in 18.04.1 after some update. I guess. I will restart my pc later, and see if it goes away. Also, I believe due to reasons cited above, no question should be closed. Let it remain open for ever and ever...

Comment: This question should not be closed, its still a bug, its still happening - happening to me right now as I ran some updates in the background while in a video chat - out of no where, my tty started switching! Very odd while in the middle of a meeting :)

Comment: I'd also like to reopen this question - I experience the same behavior.

Comment: I’ve voted to reopen this question given the recent activity. If it is reopened, I will also add a bounty to draw attention - hopefully someone will have an answer! @Todd, did a restart fix this issue, or is it persistent? Please could you [edit] my question with any details you have! I’ll try and approve the edits.

Comment: @flawr See the above comment - please do [edit] this question with any pertinent information! I’ll try and approve the edits.

Comment: @nirala Do you remember if the restart fixed this issue? Sorry to dredge up from so long ago! If you can remember anything else, see the above comments, and [edit] anything relevant into my question! I’ll try and approve the edits.

Comment: @Tim restarting did "fix" my issue

Comment: I had the exact same issue for the exact same reason, also after an upgrade. A restart fixed my problem as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your <kbd>Super</kbd> key can switch from performing as expected when your keyboard mode switches from raw. (Good explanation of the differences between keyboard modes can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16555)). This occurred to me after using the Magic <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key to switch the keyboard from raw mode while my system slowed while paging memory.

You can check what mode your keyboard is in with `sudo kbd_mode` and if it is not in raw change it back with `sudo kbd_mode -s`. Full info at https://linux.die.net/man/1/kbd_mode

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be caused by an update changing something. A restart should fix your issues, and go back to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> snapping a window to half the screen, not changing tty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct command is Control-Super-Arrow to get your present window into half screen left (or right)  Just to clear up a point.